# Write int variable in file using write

Tags: c, file, unix, ascii, c-standard-library

I'm currently trying to write an integer variable using write function in the file. This is my code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){
int fd, nbMult, i;
char buf[4];
if((fd = open("data", O_CREAT|O_RDWR, 0777))==-1){
    perror("ERROR\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE); 
}

do{ 
    printf("Bla bla ");
    if( scanf("%d", &nbMult) !=1 ) while( (i = getchar()) != '\n' );
}while(nbMult<1);
sprintf(buf, "%d", nbMult);
if( write(fd, buf, sizeof(int)) == -1 ){
    perror("ERROR\n");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
}

close(fd);
return 0; }
```

It creates the file, but when I try to open it, it shows me "cannot display ". When I remplace the name of the file by data.txt it works but it shows strange character in the file. I have tried also to convert the Integer variable to String using sprintf() and it's the same issue.

Comment: How do you "access" the file?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between binary and text files?

Comment: I mean when I try to open the file

Comment: _"I have tried also to convert the Integer variable to String using sprintf() and it's the same issue."_: don't describe your code put [edit] your question and show it _there_

Comment: _I try to open the file_: how?

Comment: If you want the file to contain readable text instead of binary, then something like sprintf() or fprintf() is the way to go. Show us that code, and we'll show you where you went wrong.

Comment: by typing gedit data in the console

Comment: I have edited the code and added the spritnf()

Comment: `write(fd, buf, sizeof(int))` -> `write(fd, buf, strlen(buf))`. And `char buf[4]` -> `char buf[100]`, 4 is a bit short

Comment: Yes, now that it's text, sizeof(int) no longer applies, it's the size of the text that you need (i.e. strlen()). And you should probably add a \n just to be nice.

Comment: the same thing, because I allocated 4 bytes for buf.

Comment: @stark actually I don't know the difference. and I think that's the issue, because with my code I create a binary file.

Comment: @AnasMK read my last comment.  `char buf[4]` -> `char buf[100]`.

Comment: @MichaelWalz, Yea it works now perfectly when I changed char buf[4] to char buf[100]. but I don't understand why?

Comment: If you try to put say 5 bytes into a buffer that has a length of 4, you'll get into trouble. Google "c buffer overflow" and "C undefined behaviour"

Comment: @AnasMK, text is for humans. Computers use numbers. You have to convert one to the other whenever you take input from humans or print output for humans, but in between the computer doesn't store numbers as text--that would be wasteful and slow. It stores them as binary numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The file does get created - and has `sizeof(int)` bytes. Its contents are the bytes making up the integer nbMult in memory.

The thing is, those are *not* the characters used to *print* `nbMult` on a terminal. For example, suppose you've typed in 1234 for `nbMult`. What you've typed in are actually the characters `'1', '2', '3', '4'` - whose numeric values are 49, 50, 51, 52 respectively ([here](http://www.c4learn.com/c-programs/program-to-print-all-ascii-value-table.html)'s a program which illustates that). But the bytes you'll get in memory for `nbMult`, on a typical machine, are 210, 4, 0, 0, since:

```
* 210 ==  1234       % 2^8
*   4 == (1234/2^ 8) % 2^8
*   0 == (1234/2^16) % 2^8
*   0 == (1234/2^24) % 2^8
```

those are the "strange characters" you're seeing in the file.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that now ^^
I appreciate your help

Comment: @AnasMK: If you found this answer helpful, you can accept it by pressing the "v" sign on the margin.